# In a string, remove parentheses with just numbers

Tags: ios, objective-c

I imagine you'd need to use regex to accomplish this, but essentially I'd like a string to go from:

> Some text (123)

to:

> Some text

But would need a string like `Other text (Mixed123)` to remain the same.

What would the code for this look like? Thanks in advance!

Comment: NSScanner would be another option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isaac's answer helped point me in the right direction, but ultimately, this is what worked:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[(][0-9]+[)]" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
name = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:STRING options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [STRING length]) withTemplate:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using the `NSRegularExpression` class. The code for running this is relatively straight forward. However, my regex skills are not my strongest suit, so I hope I got the expression right. Hope this helps.

```
NSString *string = @"Some text (123)";
NSError *error;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\([0-9]+\)"
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive 
                                                                         error:&error];

if (error)
{
    // Match failed, handle this.
}

NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:string
                                  options:0
                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches)
{
    NSRange *matchRange = [match range];
    string = [string stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:matchRange withString:@""];
}
```

Comment: Your answer helped point me in the right direction, but I added an answer with the code that worked for me

Comment: Happy to help. I didn't realize that method; simplifies it nicely.